# Check if object created with Object.create is instance of original object

Tags: javascript, object

If I create an `Object` using `Object.create`, how can I check if that new `Object` is an instance of the old `Object`

Here is an example to explain what I mean

```js
var MyClass = {
  property: null
};

MyClass[Symbol.toStringTag] = "My Class";

function newMyClass(property) {
  var instance = Object.create(MyClass);
  instance.property = property;
  return instance;
}

console.log(newMyClass() instanceof MyClass);
```

To further clarify, I am **not** asking about this

```js
function MyClass(property) {
  this.property = property;
}

console.log(new MyClass() instanceof MyClass);
```

Or this

```js
function MyClass(property) {
  this.property = property;
}

console.log(Object.create(MyClass.prototype) instanceof MyClass);
```

Comment: The first `MyClass` is not a class (ie a constructor functon or `class`). It is just a plain object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instance` can only be used with constructor functions that have `.prototype` objects. For raw prototypical inheritance, use [`isPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf):

```
console.log(MyClass.isPrototypeOf(newMyClass()));
```

You could also traverse the chain manually with `Object.getPrototypeOf`, or use it to check whether an object is a *direct* descendant.

Comment: I don't suppose there is a keyword for that? like `class isPrototypeOf instance`

Comment: No, there is not. It's an `Object.prototype` method. The syntactically appealing keywords are only for the class pattern.

Comment: Ok. I was just wondering if both were implemented like with `typeof`

Answer (score 1):

> how can I check if that new Object is an instance of the old Object

That really is the wrong question because the answer to "what is this an instance of" will always be a function (a constructor) or `null`. The argument you provide to `Object.create` is not a constructor but a prototype object (also known as proto). So if you want to know the prototype object, just check with `Object.getPrototypeOf`:

```js
var MyClass = {
  property: null
};

MyClass[Symbol.toStringTag] = "My Class";

function newMyClass(property) {
  var instance = Object.create(MyClass);
  instance.property = property;
  return instance;
}

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(newMyClass()) === MyClass);
```